# Typescript definition files for SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK?

Tags: javascript, canvas, sdk

Is there a typescript definition file for SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK?

I am converting my code to typescript and the `Sfdc` variable does not work in my code because I am missing a typescript definition for it.

I can make something to get it going, but thought I would look/ask around for a pre-built `.d.ts` definition file first.

Comment: @SMGoodyear has done stuff with typescript and salesforce. Maybe he knows.

Comment: Can you share the exact error? Perhaps I can help.

Comment: I spent time building something that would generate .d.ts for the org's metadata and remote actions. I never came across any definitions for the SDKs. Would be great to have them and add them into somewhere like definatelytyped

Comment: @SMGoodyear would you please share how to generate org's metadata definitions. That would really help to get started with TypeScript in salesforce.      Is there any blog post on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got my typescript compiling:

- Make a file called `cavans-all.d.ts`
- Put this in it:

  declare var Sfdc: any;

I put it at `Scripts/typings/sales-force`, but I don't think that matters as long as it is added to the scripts for you project.